# How to reverse engineer figures that have the 'k' or 'm' abbreviations in Excel

Tags: excel

Struggling to find a simple answer online anywhere for this, but I need to manipulate data regularly and often the source that i'm copying from presents laerge numbers in an abbreviated format. I'd like to see if there's a way to quickly reformat these numbers to contain the correct number of 0's and remove the decimal point.

For example, here's a list showing random values attributed to similarly random items (assume the fruit is in column A and the value is in column B). I'd like to have 15M change to 15000000; 12.3M change to 12300000 and; 10.03M to 10030000.

Apple 15M
Banana 12.3M
Carrot 10.03M

The only way I have found to do this has been to use the FIND AND REPLACE ALL function and go through manually replacing ".3M" with "300000" and ".03M" with "030000.

I feel like there should be an easier way.

Comment: You could run `SUBSTITUTE` for `M` with `00000` on that column, no?

Comment: do you want the output in the same cell, which would require vba, or in a new column, which can be done with formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner Happy to have it in a new column. Can do some simple formatting to arrange the table as I need afterwards.

Comment: @BruceWayne No, because the number of 0's will change dependent upon how many numbers are after the decimal point. That's what I'm currently doing right now and when there are hundreds of rows all with different combinations of numbers after the decimal place it's time intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a new column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M",B1)),SUBSTITUTE(B1,"M","")*1000000,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("K",B1)),SUBSTITUTE(B1,"K","")*1000,B1))
```

[image]

Comment: You absolute legend. Just saved me so much time. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`=-LOOKUP(1,-SUBSTITUTE(B1,{"M","K",""},"")*10^{6,3,0})`

Regards